# The speaker of the quote

Tags: knowledge, rebus, quote

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Find out whose words are these?**

Comment: "Pentagon tick bomb hi umpire drop shed" -- Albert Einstein.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The speaker is

> Mao Zedong

and the quotation is

> Poly ticks [is] war with out blood shed.

Or, as it is more usually given,

> Politics is war without bloodshed.

Comment: I don't get how the 4th and 5th picture gives 'without', could someone / Gareth explains?  thanks

Comment: "With" is a bit weak (unless I'm missing something): just two people being conspicuously together. "Out" is because the picture shows a cricket umpire making the sign that indicates that a batsman is out and has to stop batting.